# Skinning Google Maps To Look Like The Native Google Maps iPhone App

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I could use a goog set of eyes on my project.  I am designing a skin for the google maps API that resembles the native Google Maps App on the iPhone.  Ive already got it:

1) Displaying a custom info window

2) Custom pins/markers

3) Pins falling from the sky on load

4) Pulling data from an XML file

Unfortunately I can not get it working correctly on the iPhone and I think it is because my code is improperly formatted.

The map and link to the source code is available here:

http://www.brainbackup.net/post/replicating-the-google-maps-iphone-app.html

Thanks for your help!

Comment: HeyHey, firefox crashed over that link.

Answer (score 1):

turns out this had to do with the version of google maps I was using.  2.0 allows for the custom infowindow, but does not allow the pins to fall from the sky.  the opposite was true for v 2.123.  go figure.